# Relay modern pagination without viewer

Tags: pagination, graphql, relayjs, relaymodern

Hello i have done my server grapqhl api. Currently i'm stack on relay pagination in client. I searched many articles about that. And everywhere pagination done with viewer root query field. Which about it in docs said that field is unnecassary.

In other resourses:

```
query routesOrdersQuery {
  viewer {
    ...Order_order
  }
}
fragment Order_order on OrderType {
  orders() @connection {
    edges {
      node {
      }
    }
  }
```

In my case:

```
query routesOrdersQuery {
  ...Order_order
}
fragment Order_order on Query {
 orders(first: $first) @connection(key: "Order_order") {
   edges{
    node{
     id
    }
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Assumption about spreading fragment in root query is not right.
Problem lays in Route render method.

```
<Route
    render={({error, props}) => {
       if(error) {
         return <div>{error.message}</div>
       } else if(props) {
         return <Orders query={props} />
       } else {
         return <div>Loading...</div>
       }
    }}
    ...
/>
```

So use render instead of component. And it should render 3 different states. Otherwise it not work.